# Specify external HTML file for Html config in Extjs6 modern panel

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I am trying to use the html config in an Extjs6 modern panel to load up an external HTML file, like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
  html: '.../locationOfHtmlFile/htmlFile.html"
})
```

It seems like this sort of thing was possible in older versions of Extjs, or the non-modern version, but not in modern. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Modern

For Modern I think the neatest way to do this is by creating a new class with a url config:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.LoadablePanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    config:{
        url:false
    },
    updateUrl:function(url){
    if(url){    
        Ext.Ajax.request({
              url: url,
              scope:this,
              success: function(response) {
                  this.setHtml(response.responseText);
              }
            });  
        }
    }
});
```

Then you create like so:

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    url: '.../locationOfHtmlFile/htmlFile.html'
});
```

Because we are defining a config, and an update method whenever the url changes it would update. e.g. `panel.setUrl('newUrl.html');`

We could also add a reload method to make it possible to refresh:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.LoadablePanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    config:{
        url:false
    },
    updateUrl:function(url){
    if(url){    
        Ext.Ajax.request({
              url: url,
              scope:this,
              success: function(response) {
                  this.setHtml(response.responseText);
              }
            });  
        }
    },
    reload:function(){
        //just fire our update method with the current url.
        this.updateUrl(this.getUrl());
    }
});
```

### Further update

A further update that seems logical is to add a loading mask...

```
Ext.define('MyApp.LoadablePanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    config:{
        url:false
    },
    updateUrl:function(url){
    if(url){    
        this.setMasked({
            xtype:'loadmask',message:'Loading...'
        });
        Ext.Ajax.request({
              url: url,
              scope:this,
              success: function(response) {
                  this.setHtml(response.responseText);
                  this.setMasked(false);
              }
            });  
        }
    },
    reload:function(){
        //just fire our update method with the current url.
        this.updateUrl(this.getUrl());
    }
});
```

## Classic

For classic you can do this via a loader config:

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
   loader: {
        url: '.../locationOfHtmlFile/htmlFile.html',
        autoLoad: true
    }
});
```

This also means you can then refresh if needed too: `panel.getLoader().load();`

See http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.ComponentLoader.html for more details and options.

Answer (score 2):

You should load your content before, this might help:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
  url: '.../locationOfHtmlFile/htmlFile.html',
  success: function(response) {
    Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
      html: response.responseText
    });
  }
});
```